# Which of the following query is optimised/preferred

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider two table
tableA and tableB

### tableA

### |id|driver_id|vehicle_id|is_allowed|license_number|driver_name|

### tableB

### |id|driver_id|vehicle_id|offence|payable_amount|driver_name|

Goal: find driver_id and vehicle_id of allowed driver whose name is XYZ.

Query1:SELECT * FROM tableA,tableB {join-condition}{filter-condition}

```
SELECT tableA.driver_id,tableA.vehicle_id FROM tableA,tableB 
WHERE
tableA.driver_id=tableB.driver_id AND 
tableA.vehicle_id=tableB.vehicle_id AND
tableA.driver_name='XYZ' AND
tableB.driver_name='XYZ' AND
tableA.is_allowed = 1
```

Query2:SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA {filter-condition}) JOIN (SELECT * FROM tableB {filter-condition}) ON {join-condition}{filter-condition}

```
SELECT tableAA.driver_id,tableAA.vehicle_id FROM 
(SELECT tableA.driver_id,tableA.vehicle_id from tableA WHERE tableA.driver_name='XYZ' AND
tableA.is_allowed = 1) as tableAA,
JOIN
(SELECT tableB.driver_id,tableB.vehicle_id from tableB WHERE tableB.driver_name='XYZ') as tableBB
ON
tableAA.driver_id=tableBB.driver_id AND 
tableAA.vehicle_id=tableBB.vehicle_id
```

which type of query is readable, optimized and according to standard.

Comment: Always use the explicit JOIN sytax. The first query is just super old legacy code

Comment: Shouldn't `tableA.driver_id=tableB.driver_id` imply that `tableA.driver_name=tableB.driver_name`?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: @redneb, it may be and may not be, since both values are editable by a user, so both tables might have a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct version would look like this:

```
SELECT a.driver_id, a.vehicle_id
FROM tableA a JOIN
     tableB b
     ON a.driver_id = b.driver_id AND 
        a.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id
WHERE a.driver_name = 'XYZ' AND
      b.driver_name = 'XYZ' AND
      a.is_allowed = 1;
```

Notes:

- `JOIN` is accepted as the right way to combine tables in the `FROM` clause.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- The `ON` clause should contain all predicates that contain columns from more than one table.
- The use of table aliases is a preference that makes queries easier to write and to read.
- You might want to use `IN` or `EXISTS`, because your query is not returning columns from `TableB`.
- Do not use unnecessary subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  In some databases (notably MySQL), this impedes the use of indexes and adds additional overhead for materialization of the intermediate table.

And, the answer to your question is that the first version is probably the optimized version (because it does not materialize subqueries unnecessarily).  Neither version is preferred.

Comment: thanks for Notes, it would be great if you suggest some more points/blogs.

Comment: @dkb . . . I write books on the subject, so I recommend my books.

Comment: found nice articles for beginners,
http://joinfu.com/presentations/dqm/legend_drunken_query_master.pdf
http://joinfu.com/presentations/joinfu/joinfu_part_one.pdf
http://joinfu.com/presentations/joinfu/joinfu_part_two.pdf

Answer (score 0):

First one is better in case of standard and performance but is very old fashioned so it can be written in this way

```
SELECT tableA.driver_id,tableA.vehicle_id 
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.driver_id=tableB.driver_id 
    AND tableA.vehicle_id=tableB.vehicle_id 
    AND tableA.driver_name='XYZ' 
    AND tableB.driver_name='XYZ' 
    AND tableA.is_allowed = 1
```